# Replace characters 92-97 in position "x" on line

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk, formatting

I have two files, and need to grab the text from character positions 92-97 in each line of `file1` and use it to replace the same section of the corresponding line in `file2`.

For example:

**File1**

```
LOCAR0013LOCBLKAR0013LOCDEFAR0013LOC024500230012BLKAR0013              7Q3G013             003340000000000000

LOCAR0030LOCBLKAR0030LOCDEFAR0030LOC091500960004BLKAR0030              M20G010             000165000000000000

LOCAR0031LOCBLKAR0031LOCDEFAR0031LOC024500230012BLKAR0031              M21G011             002240000000000000
```

**File2**

```
LOCAR0013LOCBLKAR0013LOCDEFAR0013LOC024500230012BLKAR0013              7Q3G4GR             000040000000000000

LOCAR0030LOCBLKAR0030LOCDEFAR0030LOC091500960004BLKAR0030              M20GTRS             000105000000000000

LOCAR0031LOCBLKAR0031LOCDEFAR0031LOC024500230012BLKAR0031              M21G2AS             000040000000000000
```

**Expected output to New file**

```
LOCAR0013LOCBLKAR0013LOCDEFAR0013LOC024500230012BLKAR0013              7Q3G4GR             003340000000000000

LOCAR0030LOCBLKAR0030LOCDEFAR0030LOC091500960004BLKAR0030              M20GTRS             000165000000000000

LOCAR0031LOCBLKAR0031LOCDEFAR0031LOC024500230012BLKAR0031              M21G2AS             002240000000000000
```

I have this on a Unix / Solaris system.

Comment: What part of this is giving you problems? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of reading in line by line from both files, doing a cut -c 92-97 into a variable, then taking that variable and replacing value in file2 with variable and outputting to a new file - I have got the cut into a variable so far and just working on the rest.

Comment: take the 2nd row. the 1st column in file1 and file2 are different (`9150096` and `9150172` ) 2nd column are different too. why the replacement should be done on that row??

Comment: Apologies that is my silly mistake when pasting the contents... I will correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one-liner should work:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=substr($0,92,5);next}($1 in a) {$0=substr($0,1,92) a[$1] substr($0,97)}1' file file2
```

Comment: Thanks Kent, 2 in 1 day from you... legend.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;

open my $fh1, '<', $file1;
open my $fh2, '<', $file2;

while (my $line2 = <$fh2>) {
    my $line1 = <$fh1>);
    if (defined $line1) {
        substr($line2, 91, 6) = substr($line1, 91, 6);
    }
    print $line2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1,$5,$3}' OFS='\t\t'
LOCAR0013LOCBLKAR0013LOCDEFAR0013LOC024500230012BLKAR0013       7Q3G4GR     003340000000000000

LOCAR0030LOCBLKAR0030LOCDEFAR0030LOC091500960004BLKAR0030       M20GTRS     000165000000000000

LOCAR0031LOCBLKAR0031LOCDEFAR0031LOC024500230012BLKAR0031       M21G2AS     002240000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you load the files into memory in perl:

```
my @file1 = <$fh1>;
my @file2 = <$fh2>;

for my $line (0 .. $#file1) {
    my $replace = substr($file1[$line], 91, 6);  # take your string from file1
    substr($file2[$line], 91, 6) = $replace;     # put it into file2
}
```

You will now have the altered lines in `@file2`.

The `substr` function can also be used as an lvalue, and have a value assigned to it, which is what we do here.

Comment: The substrings are six characters long at offset 91, not five at offset 92

Comment: @Borodin Fixed. Though I think with these kinds of data, the OP must tweak it himself.